# iOS: why two graphic contexts here and one extra mem copy?

Tags: ios, optimization, bitmap

I found many examples how to blit an array of ints onto the `UIView` in `drawRect`, but the simplest one still puzzling me. This works OK, but still three questions:

~ why two contexts?

~ why `push`/`pop` context?

~ can avoid copy? *([Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html%20Apple%20docs) say that CGBitmapContextCreateImage copy memory block)*

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGColorSpaceRef color = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    int PIX[9] = {  0xff00ffff,0xff0000ff,0xff00ff00,
                        0xff0000ff,0xff00ffff,0xff0000ff,
                        0xff00ff00,0xff0000ff,0xff00ffff};
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate((void*)PIX,3,3,8,4*3,color,kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(color);
    CGContextRef c=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextDrawImage(c, CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10), image);
    CGImageRelease(image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method is drawing the array to 3x3 sized image, then drawing that image onto a 10x10 size in the current context, which is this case would be your `UIView`'s `CALayer`.

`UIGraphicsPushContext` lets you set the `CGContext` that you are *currently* drawing to. So before the first call, your current `CGContext` is the `UIView`, then you push the new `CGContext` which is the image that is being drawn to.

The `UIGraphicsPopContext` call restores the *previous* context, which is the `UIView`, then you get a reference to that context, and draw the created image to it using this line:

```
CGContextDrawImage(c, CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10), image);
```

As far as avoiding the copy operation, the docs say that it is sometime a copy on write, but they don't specify when those conditions occur:

`The CGImage object returned by this function is created by a copy operation. Subsequent changes to the bitmap graphics context do not affect the contents of the returned image. In some cases the copy operation actually follows copy-on-write semantics, so that the actual physical copy of the bits occur only if the underlying data in the bitmap graphics context is modified. As a consequence, you may want to use the resulting image and release it before you perform additional drawing into the bitmap graphics context. In this way, you can avoid the actual physical copy of the data.`